# Retrieving Access Token Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I have several video files in Firebase Storage and I would like to retrieve their access tokens in order to stream them back. For now if I want to play any of them I have to manually copy their access token which is not feasible for what I'm trying to achieve. So is there a way to do this without having to download them?